# Add windows explorer extension for specific files

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to add a context menu item in windows explorer if the file type specified is .exe?  i.e. if someone right clicks, a context menu item to send it to the av, or to add to PATH, or whatever.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You need to add a shell command in the registry.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).